# Cron Jobs, Task Queue or Deferred Tasks?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task

In Google App Engine, for a task like scanning some RSS feeds and adding new entries from the feed to the datastore **every 10-15 seconds**, should I use [Cron Jobs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html), [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) or [Deferred Tasks](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html)? I'm really confused.

Comment: Why do you need to insert the data so often?

Comment: @Adam Matan: What's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just curious - it's quite uncommon to read an `RSS` feed so frequently, and it might get you blocked as if you're DDOS-ing the feed.

Comment: Chances are whoever provides the RSS feed is going to block you - or possibly hunt you down and leave burning poo on your doorstep - for polling every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke a cron job every 1 minute, which would get the `RSS` and sleep for 15 seconds four times. You can locks to prevent overlapping (although the database insertion provides some measure of concurrency control).

Python-like pseudo code:

```
if cant_get_lock:
    exit
else:
for i in (1,2,3,4):
    get RSS
    sleep 15 seconds
```

Comment: No. Don't sleep in App Engine request handlers. Use the task queue instead.

Comment: @Nick Please post a task queue answer.

Answer (score 0):

- I think if it happens every 15
  seconds(not skipping) than I would cron jobs
  because that is easiest to
  implement. But if you need to be able
  cancel task then you should use task
  queue.
- BTW you should use [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/)(hubbub) to
  receive updates for the feeds in
  realtime if I understand you
  correctly.

Comment: Isn't cron limited to jobs that run every minute?

Comment: @Lott I guess you are right about that. So than he always needs task queue for his use case I guess. Still I think he is doing feed polling or something which should be avoided.

Comment: No, cron can run in fractional minutes.